# Akka-Persistence : how to fetch a snapshot

Tags: scala, akka, snapshot, akka-persistence

How can we query an old snapshot in akka-persistence ?

I can see that the `SnapshotStore` has a `LoadSnapshot` message that is privately available but not available to call otherwise.

there is an interface in `snapshotter` -> `loadSnapshot`

but this gives a callback to the actor, and is not what I need.

```
  /**
   * Instructs the snapshot store to load the specified snapshot and send it via an [[SnapshotOffer]]
   * to the running [[PersistentActor]].
   */
  def loadSnapshot(persistenceId: String, criteria: SnapshotSelectionCriteria, toSequenceNr: Long) =
    snapshotStore ! LoadSnapshot(persistenceId, criteria, toSequenceNr)
```

I basically need a way to `ask` the snapshot store to give me a snapshot that I need.

Is there a way to do that ? Why has it been made explicitly private and not callable ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to explicitly request a certain snapshot.

Snapshots are offered to the persistent actor during recovery in `SnapshotOffer` messages. By default the latest snapshot is offered to the actor, but this can be customized by overriding `recovery` and supplying custom `SnapshotSelectionCriteria`. See also http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/persistence.html#Snapshots